# CRM 2011 - Refresh a single field on a form with javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'am looking for a script that will refresh a single field on the form after it was updated by a plugin that was triggered when a new record was added to a subform on that form.

Is this possible or do i have to refresh the whole window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way to just refresh one field. You could just retrieve the current record through the web service and set the value on the form to the new value, though.

Comment: feew, that's what i just did XD But i thought that would be to strange to do. But if you say so.. :)

Comment: Could you perhaps post your code so that it could be used by others who have a similar problem?